# How can I view/open a word document in my browser using with PHP or HTML

Tags: php, html, file, ms-word

How can I open and view a `.doc` file extension in my browser? The file is located on my server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two options: First is to just link to it, e.g. `<a href="MyWordDocument.doc">My Word Document</a>`, the second is to use an iframe and point it to the document. For this to work, however, most browsers require that the server sends a `Content-disposition: inline` header with the document. If you cannot configure your web server to do this, you can wrap the document in a bit of php:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: application/msword'); // not sure if this is the correct MIME type
readfile('MyWordDocument.doc');
exit;
```

And then link to that script instead of your word document.

This isn't guaranteed to work though; the content-disposition header is just a hint, and any browser may choose to treat it as an attachment anyway.

Also, note that .doc isn't exactly portable; basically, you need Word to display it properly (Open Office and a few other Open Source applications do kind of a decent job, but they're not quite there yet), and the browser must support opening Word as a plugin.

If the .doc file format requirement isn't set in stone, PDF would be a better choice (the conversion is usually as simple as printing it on a PDF printer, say, CutePDF, from inside Word), or maybe you can even convert the document to HTML (mileage may vary though).

Comment: It is true that open office is not 100% accurate at displaying `.doc` files, but the same can be said of MS-Word. I have had about the same failure rate for both; It is the `.doc` format that is the problem.

Comment: how can I create something editable, like once opened if someone makes changes in that it gets updated on the server?

Answer (score 6):

```
<a href="foo.doc">…</a>
```

You will need a browser with a plugin for Office documents installed. I believe Microsoft Office will install one for at least Internet Explorer by default.

If you want to work without a plugin, then you will need to convert the document to another format — HTML for maximum compatibility. This isn't a trivial operation, especially for complex documents (or even those which just contain images).

Answer (score 5):

```
$file = "$file_name.doc";
$len = filesize($file); // Calculate File Size
ob_clean();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public"); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type:application/zip"); // Send type of file
$header="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$patient_name.zip;"; // Send File Name
header($header );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$len); // Send File Size
@readfile($file);
```

Comment: I tried the `header`s of the other answers and the file was corrupted, with this answer's `header`s finally worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can use google docs instead as it is free and reliable
You can assign your file path to iframe.

e.g. iframe1.Attributes.Add("Src", "http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://***YOUR_FILE_PATH***&embedded=true");

Comment: Very nice! i did not know this.

Comment: http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=<Document Location> <- Microsoft version

Comment: but documents are not secured because it is publicly available.

Comment: how can I disable download button?

Comment: Nicely done...Thanks. Although i used it in download button

Answer (score 4):

If your .doc file is accessable online, you can try [Office Web Viewer](http://blogs.office.com/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/) service.

If your documents stored in Intranet, you can use [Microsoft Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps) Server. It allows users to view Word, PowerPoint, Excel documents via browser.

Comment: what about password protected file ? I mean my doc file, accessible after login.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Edit
$header="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.doc;"; // Send File Name
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and proposed solution. I'm sure the OP would appreciate some elaboration on how to use this and what it does.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This will download the file (with other header params included)