# How to display a file on an HTML page with javascript from POST data sent via a Flex URLRequest?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, post

I'm trying to add "file preview" functionality to my Flex app.  I have a LinkButton in Flex that, when clicked, should open the file in a new browser window.  I found a helpful actionscript class that properly formats the POST data to pass the file to an HTML page.  The file POST data is put into a URLRequest, which is sent to the HTML page through a URLLoader.

My problem is that I'm not very experienced with Javascript and I don't know how to tell the HTML page to display the file being sent by the Flex app.  After countless web searches, I decided to ask here.  I'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me, I just need a good place to start from (a keyword, a javascript function to read about, something).

I would like to use a combination of HTML and Javascript to take the POST data and open the included file in the browser.

Other important information: the file needs to be displayed in IE8 and the files being displayed are mostly image files, PDFs, or Word docs.

Edit:
Here is some info I forgot to mention.  The files I want to display are being stored in the database.  I'm grabbing the file from there and storing in a custom class as a ByteArray.  I then pass the ByteArray to my helper class that formats the POST data request and stores the result in URLRequest.data.

Here's what my request looks like:

```
--lljcuqjclcnyicgrmwexayhafmkhiwfx

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"



arrows.png

--lljcuqjclcnyicgrmwexayhafmkhiwfx

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="arrows.png"

Content-Type: image/png



?PNG

"image information as ByteArray"



--lljcuqjclcnyicgrmwexayhafmkhiwfx

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"



Submit Query

--lljcuqjclcnyicgrmwexayhafmkhiwfx--
```

So I'm looking for a way (using Javascript and HTML ideally) to handle that request and have the browser display the file (or display an open/save dialog if the user doesn't have the proper plugins to display).

Comment: image preview you can do in flex with file reference.load() and grab the byteArray from the complete event.  For the pdfs... this looks like it might help [jspdf](http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf)

Answer (score 0):

First simple case want to display images or pdf (plugins needed)

```
navigateToUrl(new URLRequest("http://localhost/images/hello.png"));
```

If you want something pass data to html page you need to consider following code

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.localhost/openfile.html");
req.data = "path='http://localhost/images/hello.png'";
req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
navigateToURL(req);
```

After  that you need to get the path value from javascript [GET Parameter values through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) then you can parse GET parameter then you can play with DOM elements.

I thought we can't get the POST value from JavaScript alone we need to use server scripts.[Post-variables-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery) .

MS Words to open in browser it will help [View/Open Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346117/how-can-i-view-open-a-word-document-in-my-browser-using-with-php-or-html). I am not sure about Word Docs.

Comment: I can't use navigateToUrl because the files I want to display are being stored in the database, and I can't access them through a URL.  I'm currently pulling the file out of the database into a custom class that stores the file as a ByteArray.  I then pass the ByteArray into my helper class that formats the POST data and I store the results from that into the URLRequest.data.

Comment: Please see the edit to my original question above. And thanks for the reply.