# How to view the uploaded(.doc) file in a div?

Tags: php, html, ms-word, ms-office

I uploaded the .doc file using php code and saved it in a folder ,the path is stored in database.

When i tried to make a view of the doc file in a div ...a dialog box appears asking whether to save or openwith ..

I'm using wampserver ....I just tried like this

```
<iframe name="awindow" frameborder=2 width=580 height=440 src="www/siva_example/pdf/1_siva.doc"></iframe>
```

Any help regarding..
Is it possible to view .doc file in browser or i have to convert it to pdf format...

Comment: You can't display a doc file within the html, unless you decode the file, convert it to html, with a php decoder, like [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to display a .doc[x] in HTML. You can try to convert the .doc[x] to HTML or to an image.

Answer (score 0):

you can view doc file by adding this to your header at request time

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: inline');
header('Content-type: application/msword'); 
// not sure if this is the correct MIME type
readfile('MyWordDocument.doc');
exit;
```

Comment: it should work. if not. try these same question solution over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346117/how-can-i-view-open-a-word-document-in-my-browser-using-with-php-or-html

Comment: I hope you read the comment below the answer mentioned.."This isn't guaranteed to work though; "

Answer (score 0):

You could try using google docs for this, use the below code, it works perfectly for ppts, have not been able to test it for a doc yet

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://yourdomain.com/document.doc&embedded=true" style="width:550px; height:450px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Ofcourse you would have to update the url as per your program using PHP

Comment: no - it has to be a publicly accessible URL for this to work. It also has limitations - for even semi-popular sites its easy to run into rate limits, and get an error.

Comment: agreed with @sevenseacat btw why would you need this to work on localhost... just a little curious