# How do i edit doc files in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, doc

I have been wondering how I can edit Doc or Docx files in PHP or would it be easier to convert to a different format what would I use and how. I already know that Doc files are Binary and docx are zip and XML docs etc.

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346117/how-can-i-view-open-a-word-document-in-my-browser-using-with-php-or-html) and a fiew others that I cannot remember and it just downloaded (something I don't want to do) the docx file.

What should I use?
What libary works with what editor?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't tell us what you are trying to do ;-) Could you be a bit more specific? Then we may be able to tell you whether you might use docx format or another format.

Comment: You'll need a specific library to read and edit Word documents in PHP, such as [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) for example.

Comment: What library works with what editor and or Code to work with the library atm i dont understand them sorry

Comment: Are you looking for a templating engine for docx ? Have you tried : https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater (written in javascript by myself) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well generally it is a bad idea to try to edit binary files by yourself.

Why not try any library implementing Word file editing?

e.g. check out https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: The other option is to avoid microsoft and run a headless libra Office. Not sure if there is a good php library?